# Não consigo ler o arquivo python

Tags: python, pdf

preciso realizar uma baixa todos os dias de um determinado documento e ler o arquivo, eu gerei os códigos para ele sempre buscar o primeiro documento desta pasta atualizado, porem na hora de ler o documento, me aparece esse retorno, alguém poderia saber o motivo? Detalhe que já fiz um código somente para ler o arquivo e deu certo, abriu o arquivo, porém quando eu tento ler esse que está puxando o mais atualizado, não consigo.

```
 caminho = (r"C:\Users\Otavio.cunha\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\teste" )

    lista_arquivos = os.listdir(caminho)
    
    lista_data = []
    
    for arquivos in lista_arquivos:
        data = os.path.getmtime(f"{caminho}/{arquivos}")
        lista_data.append((data , arquivos))
        
    
    lista_data.sort(reverse=True)
    ultimo_arquivo = lista_data
    
    
    
    for abrir in ultimo_arquivo: 
        with open(str(abrir[1])): 
            dados = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(abrir)
            pagina = dados.getPage(0)
            texto = pagina.extract_text()
            print(texto[1])
```

**Aparece esse erro:** FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "(1668181367.0083454, 'Oiiiie.pdf')"

Comment: `lista_data.append((data , arquivos))` - vc gerou uma lista de tuplas, sendo que cada tupla contém a data e o nome do arquivo. Sendo assim, na hora de abrir o arquivo, deveria pegar somente o nome, mas vc está passando a tupla inteira. Deveria ser `with open(abrir[1])` (repare também que é `with` e não `while`)

Comment: Não estou conseguindo ainda, até coloquei outro arquivo e me trás o mesmo erro: 
**FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '007617000101011 (8).pdf'**

Comment: Não está encontrando o arquivo ainda, tente usar o caminho absoluto dele.